# fill up database with data, when forgein key exist

Tags: sql, database, foreign-keys, navicat

Table1: tb1_id, tb1_value

Table 2: tb2_id, tb2_value, **tb1_id**

The problem I have with the foreign key `tb1_id`. Is there an easy way to fill this column with values instead of id numbers. The db I have is complicated and its difficult to find out the id number for each value.
Edited:
Data example:

```
_id | col2 | col3 | col4 ....
 01 | 02   | 10   | 05
```

So columns 2, 3, 4 are foreign keys. I should fill many such column with data and I found such data very difficult to fill in because I have to look for the equivalent value for each id number.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're using two different tables, then? It seems like you want to denormalize the schema.

Comment: I should fill the db correctly with tb1_id numbers. The problem I have, I don't understand the number. I understand the value and when I know the equivalent value I can write the correct id number. So I should "translate the id number to the equivalent string value for each row. This take a lot of time from me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my question to help other people they have same issue. If someone have the same difficulty I recommend to use a good database editor software like navigate what I tried.
When someone click on any foreign key cell in navicat it shows the foreign key id and the value what the id belong to. I hope that's help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable all constraints in the database ( like the foreign Key) just run this code:

```
-- disable all constraints
EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"
```

Then you should be able to fill the value with whatever you want, null or another value.